# Setting up verbatim text within a #+CAPTION: in OrgMode

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

I want to do the following in an Org file that I'm exporting to LaTeX:

```
#+CAPTION: Yaw_Axis_Corrected.png from Wikimedia
#+ATTR_LATEX: width=5cm 
[[./Yaw_Axis_Corrected.png]]
```

but the file name gets put into a math context by the export, so the filename gets typeset with a bunch of subscripts.  Trying `#+CAPTION ~Yaw_Axis_Corrected.png~ from Wikimedia` results in no caption at all.

How can I escape the file name so that it just gets put verbatim into the caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some informal testing, I found that backslash-escaping the underscores in the filename solved the problem. Here's the entirety of my Org file:

```
#+TITLE: Goober peas

#+CAPTION: Yaw\_Axis\_Corrected.png from Wikimedia
#+ATTR_LATEX: width=5cm
[[~/tmp/Yaw_Axis_Corrected.png]]
```

Note the backslashes before the underscores in the #+CAPTION value.

And here's what it looked like when rendered to PDF. (Don't mind the lousy font rendering; that's just something I haven't yet fixed about how tex2pdf behaves on this box. Don't mind the black background, either; apparently tex2pdf does odd things with PNG transparency.)

[image: Screenshot of example Org file, rendered to PDF.]